# When emacs starts in daemon mode how can I automatically load the correct init settings when connecting via X11 or terminal?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacsclient

I recently began running emacs in daemon mode on startup. Connecting via GUI client (Emacs.app) appears to load customizations correctly. However, connecting  via `emacsclient` in Terminal does not.

The first symptom appeared after trying to `M-x customize-variable` in Terminal which produced the following message:

> Cannot save customizations: init file was not fully loaded

This may have something to do with `emacs --daemon` ignoring all X11-related options [according to this](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/daemon-vs-server-start-tp200799p200800.html). Though it would appear in my case that instead of ignoring the X11-related options emacsclient fails to load subsequent options.

After researching the problem and possible solutions I've been unable to determine a bulletproof method for dealing with this. I've seen suggestions to create a different init file and corresponding bash alias that passes it to `emacsclient --eval` each time one wants to open an emacs buffer in Terminal. And I've seen others who use if-else statements in their main init file to deal with X11-related options. But before going down one path or another I'm wondering if there's a canonical way of dealing with this that I've somehow overlooked (or if I've simply made a mistake somewhere).

Advice, criticism, tips would be much appreciated.

**Edit to add**:
* GNU Emacs 24.3.1
* emacsclient 24.3
* both installed with homebrew on OS X 10.9

Here is the LaunchAgent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>emacsdaemon</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/emacs</string>
    <string>--daemon</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ServiceDescription</key>
  <string>Emacs Daemon</string>
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>my_name</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here are the dotfile configs:

```
# relevant lines of .zshrc:
alias emacs="/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/emacsclient -nw"
# set emacsclient as default editor  
export EDITOR="emacsclient"  
# use only emacscilent  
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
```

Sometimes I also like to launch emacs from within tmux:

```
# relevant lines of .tmux.conf:
# open emacs inside of tmux in a new window
# hat tip: http://perlstalker.vuser.org/blog/2012/10/16/emacsclient-and-tmux/
bind-key y   new-window -n "emacs" "/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/emacsclient -nw"
```

Comment: Which version of Emacs? OSX users are often running quite old versions. Does this still happen with the [current release](http://emacsformacosx.com/)?

Comment: @phils, I'm running version 24.3, installed with homebrew on OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

`emacsclient` does not cause any part of the init file from being read.  I.e. in your use case, you need to setup your init file such that it covers *all* use cases (both for text-terminals and for GUI frames) since you can have several of the different kinds at the same time anyway.

The `Cannot save customizations: init file was not fully loaded` message indicates that an error was signaled while loading `~/.emacs`, so go check the contents of `*Messages*` to see what the error was and try to fix it.